# Bluetooth discoverable status on application start

Tags: android, bluetooth, onstart, discoverability

How can we have the bluetooth discoverable status on application start

I have an Image view for showing the status but its not showing the appropriate Image on start of applicaton

In oncreate() I have the following code

```
 mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


    if(mBtAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        bt_strength.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt);

    }
    else if (!mBtAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        bt_strength.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_grey);
    }
```

Even this  code also not working

```
      mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

     int status = mBtAdapter.getState();
    if(status == mBtAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE){
        bt_strength.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt);

    }
    else if (status == mBtAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE){
        bt_strength.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_grey);
    }
```

How I can get around this problem? 
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use below code

```
   mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


    if(mBtAdapter.getScanMode() == BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE)
    {
        bt_strength.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt);

    }
    else 
    {
        bt_strength.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_grey);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  I tried with ur code also but its not working

Comment: I think you are tried mBtAdapter.getState() not mBtAdapter.getScanMode().

Comment: Thanks a lot ,its working. so if the status is on/off its showing the correct image.I have one more question,  On clicking that Image view can we stop the discoverable condition before timeout

Comment: yes you can, but you need to disable the bluetooth to stop the discoverable by using mBtAdapter.disable()

Comment: APi have one more method cancelDiscovery(), you can try this